# Maximizing symmetric functions on the unit cube

Tags: optimization, symmetric-functions

Let $f:[0,1]^n \to \mathbb{R}$. We say that $f$ is symmetric, if for every permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ and every $(x_1,..,x_n) \in [0,1]^n$ we have that
$$f(x_1,..,x_n) = f(x_{\sigma(1)},...,x_{\sigma(n)})$$

I am interested in the following question. Denote by $x_* = \text{argmax}_{x\in [0,1]^n}(f(x))$. Must it be the case that $x_*$ is a diagonal element? that it, there exists $0 \leq c \leq 1$ such that  $x_* = (c,...,c)$?

If so, is there a short and intuitive explanation?

If not, any easy counterexample?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, define $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1,& x \in \{e_k\} \\
0,& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$.

Here is a continuous one:
$f(x) = \|x- {1 \over \sqrt{n}} \langle e,  x\rangle e \|_2$, where
$e=(1,...1)^T$. Then $f$ is zero on the diagonal, but $f(x)>0$ off the diagonal.

To see that that latter is permutation invariant, let $P$ be a permutation matrix, then since $Pe=P^T e = e$, and $\|Py\|_2 = \|y\|_2$, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
f(Px) &=& \|Px- {1 \over \sqrt{n}} \langle e,  Px\rangle e \|_2
\\
&=& \|Px- {1 \over \sqrt{n}} \langle P^T e,  x\rangle P e \|_2 \\
&=&
 \|Px- {1 \over \sqrt{n}} \langle P^T e,  x\rangle P e \|_2 \\
&=& \|Px- {1 \over \sqrt{n}} \langle e,  x\rangle P e \|_2 \\
&=& \|x- {1 \over \sqrt{n}} \langle e,  x\rangle  e \|_2 \\
&=& f(x)
\end{eqnarray}